# Suggesting edits to remove your earlier suggested edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just saw [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4713675). The user added the explanation "I updated this mistakenly.". So I did a little investigation. And indeed the user suggested an edit earlier which was approved. And moments later it suggested the edit to be removed.

Not sure if this is ok, it looks at least a bit shady to me.